# google stacked bar chart do not want to display 0 bar

Tags: charts, google-visualization

In a google stacked bar chart is there any way to have it not display a bar with a zero value? [image]

I do not want the thin red line on the first bar or the hover to show.

Here is my code:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Class', 'Cost', 'Savings', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['Current State Run', 140999460, 0, ''],
        ['Total Future State Run', 109351526, 31647934, '']
      ]);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1,
                { calc: "stringify",
                  sourceColumn: 1,
                  type: "string",
                  role: "annotation" },
                2, 
                { calc: formatter,
                  sourceColumn: 2,
                  type: "string",
                  role: "annotation" },
                3]);

function formatter(dataTable, row) {
    if (data.getValue(row, 2))
        return parseInt(data.getValue(row, 2)).toLocaleString()
    else
        return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the zero value to `null`,
this will hide the line and tooltip.

if needed, you can use a `DataView` and calculated columns,
to dynamically change the zeroes to `null`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Class', 'Cost', 'Savings'],
    ['Current State Run', 140999460, 0],
    ['Total Future State Run', 109351526, 31647934]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  var viewCols = [0];
  for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    addCalcs(i);
  }

  view.setColumns(viewCols);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    isStacked: true
  };

  chart.draw(view, options);

  function addCalcs(col) {
    viewCols.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return getNullValue(dt, row, col);
      },
      label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
      type: data.getColumnType(col)
    });

    viewCols.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return formatter(dt, row, col);
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    });
  }

  function formatter(dataTable, row, col) {
    if (data.getValue(row, col)) {
      return parseInt(data.getValue(row, col)).toLocaleString()
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  function getNullValue(dataTable, row, col) {
    var value = dataTable.getValue(row, col);
    if (value === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return value;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I am already using a data view because I want the bar value displayed inside the bar (role: "annotation"), and I have a calc function because it was displaying the 0 in the bar. Can I have 2 calc functions one for each role? Or can I have 2 roles assigned to 1 function?

Comment: you can definitely have multiple cal functions, see changed answer above -- the only problem with using the same calc function for multiple columns, you have to pass in the column index somehow...

Comment: Thanks so much for the very complete code example. I was able to get this working as desired.